# Mobile Logo not showing on iPads/Mobile phone

Tags: wordpress

I created this Wordpress site and inserted the logo and mobile logo through Customizer > Site identity, but the logo doest not appear on mobile phones or tablets. Any ideas?
Site: https://topstadions.nl/

I tried to change the size and some CSS stylying, but no effect.

Comment: Are you talking about your favicon ?

Comment: No, the mobile logo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ With reference your statement " tried to change the size and some CSS styling, but no effect"; please add any code to your post that you have tried. Even if it didn't produce the expected result, it will likely be a good starting point for other contributors to assist you. Please read the FAQ on creating a Minimal Reproducible Example of code for guidelines >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your favicon, I already have this issue. You can use a plugin to solve this, but if you want to do that properly, I suggest you to add your favicon by (s)FTP and add the meta code in your `header.php` file.
You can find some information right here :
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-favicon/#3-manually-adding-your-favicon-via-ftp

Comment: I mean the mobile logo, not the favicon.